# Epson Printer Utility GLib-ERROR

Tags: printing, epson

When I try to launch from terminal the freshly installed utility with command `epson-printer-utility`, the attempt fails:

```
Asarluhi@home:~ $ epson-printer-utility

(epson-printer-utility:6304): GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Do you understand the reason why I am unable to launch the utility?
I downloaded it from the [Epson download center](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX), using "sx235x" as a product name.

My system specifications:

`Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS` 
printer: `Epson stylus sx235w` 
printer driver: `1.0.0-1lsb3.2` 
scanner driver: `2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7`

Printer and scanner drivers work fine, the utility would be useful for print head alignment, nozzle check and for checking the ink levels.